# Can "so & very" modify "great"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

[Cambridge Grammar says](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adverbs-of-degree/very)

> Adjectives which describe an extreme quality can be modified by
>   absolutely, completely, really and totally but not normally with very.
>   Some common examples are:
>
> amazing, excellent, horrified, awful, exceptional, huge, brilliant, fantastic,
>   perfect, delighted, furious, stunning, essential, horrible, terrible,
>
> Her dress was absolutely stunning.
>
> Not: Her dress was very stunning.
>
> That singer is really awful.
>
> Not: That singer is very awful.
>
> It is a really fantastic film.
>
> Not: It is a very fantastic film.

[It also says](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/speaking/so)

> We also use so as an intensifier to mean ‘very, very’:
>
> That motorway is so dangerous. Everyone drives too fast.
>
> That’s kind of you. Thanks so much for thinking of us.

So, Can "**so & very**" modify "**great**"?

Is it ok to say "**It's so great**" & "**It's very great**"

Comment: "Great can have multiple meanings.  You might use "a very great amount" (adjective) but not "It's very great to see you" (adverb).  People commonly say, "It's so great to see you!"  But they might also say, "It's so very great to see you!", so go figure.

Comment: *So* and *very* are adverbs. *Great* is an adjective. Repeat after me: "An adverb modifies an adjective or another adverb." That's the thing that makes adverbs so very useful (even if Stephen King hates them) and so very great. How great? Very great.

Comment: Great comments like these pretty much guarantee that the question never gets answered properly.

Comment: "So" can be used for all the words you've mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both can be used

> so great
>   very great

though usage of "*very great*" does not easily come to mind.  In "*so great*", "*great*" is often used in place of "wonderful".

> That's *so great*.
>   *that's so wonderful*
>
> That's *so very great*!!